# EF4 Derived Entity with Derived Foreign Key Entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm using asp.net mvc3 with ef4.

I have 2 classes,

ClassA, ClassB.

ClassA has 2 ClassB's.

I have derived versions of these classes:

DerivedClassA, DerivedClassB.

DerivedClassA has ClassB,'s however I want DerivedClassA to populate it's ClassB from the DerivedClassB table and not ClassB table.

Is this possible to specify this relationship with Fluent API?  I am using TPC.

Comment: "*I want DerivedClassA to populate it's ClassB from the DerivedClassB table and not ClassB table*": Doesn't that mean basically that `DerivedClassA` should have a property of type `DerivedClassB` and not of the base class type `ClassB`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. This seems like a basic OO question.

You could try:

```
class DerivedClassA : ClassA
{
   new DerivedClassB ClassB1 { get; }
   new DerivedClassB ClassB2 { get; }
}
```